# Extract Near-Infrared (NIR) channel from a JPEG image in Android

Tags: android, image, image-processing

I am a beginner in image processing in Android. I am trying to build an application in which I need to separate the color channels from an image and perform calculations on them.

I have successfully extracted RGB channels from the image. I am using the code fragment given in these tutorials: https://xjaphx.wordpress.com/2011/06/21/image-processing-filter-color-channels/

Here is the code fragment:

```
public static Bitmap doColorFilter(Bitmap src, double red, double green, double blue) {
        int width = src.getWidth();
        int height = src.getHeight();

        Bitmap bmOut = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, src.getConfig());

        int A, R, G, B;
        int pixel;

        for(int x = 0; x < width; ++x) {
            for(int y = 0; y < height; ++y) {

                pixel = src.getPixel(x, y);

                A = Color.alpha(pixel);
                R = (int)(Color.red(pixel) * red);
                G = (int)(Color.green(pixel) * green);
                B = (int)(Color.blue(pixel) * blue);

                bmOut.setPixel(x, y, Color.argb(A, R, G, B));
            }
        }


        return bmOut;
    }
}
```

But I am unable to figure out the way to extract NIR channel from the image. My aim to extract this NIR channel is because I need to apply the NDVI (Normalised Difference Vegetation Index) indicator on the image for analysis.

Also, in this piece of code, brute-force approach has been used by running multiple for loops. Thus, the program becomes really slow with the complexity being - O(width*height). What would be an efficient way for computation of these separate channels?

Screen shot of image properties:

[image]

[image: Camera]

[image: Advance photo]

Kindly help me with this issue.

Comment: there is no such thing as NIR channel.

Comment: NIR is a spectral band in a multi-spectral image. I have to apply this formula for NDVI: (NIR - Red) / (NIR + Red). So I assumed that we would be able to extract NIR from an image as well. Am I on a wrong path? @Piglet

Comment: and what format is this multi-spectral image? how do you create it?

Comment: We are not creating the image. It is taken by a high-end camera in JPEG format. @Piglet

Comment: Are you using a special camera? If so, you should post some info about the images it produces and maybe the spec. "High end" does not mean much in this context.

Comment: @AdiShavit Yes, We have using images of survey camera. You can see the question now I have edited. I have posted screen shots of image properties.

Comment: I think you have a misconception here. Unless this camera has a special sensor that produces a dedicated NIR channel, you can only extract color channels as you have already done. You cannot extract non-color channel from regular, visible-color, camera sensors.

Comment: @AdiShavit I read the camera info. they use a dual bandpass so you see red in the red channel and nir in the blue channel.

Comment: @HarshMehta just read the manufacturer website, it is all there... even ImageJ examples

Comment: The blue channel *is* the NIR. Ignore the green channel.

Answer (score 3):

From the manufacturers website:

> NDVI Red + NIR
>
> This camera has a dual-band filter that captured reflected Red light
>   in the RGB sensor's red channel and reflected Near Infrared light in
>   the RGB sensor's blue channel. You can thus use this single camera to
>   compute the NDVI indice, though the contrast in the resulting index
>   image will not be as "accurate" as using the separate Red and NIR
>   camera models.

Comment: Thanks for this. But can you suggest a better method for this instead of the two for loops? The for loops gives a massive time overhead which degrades the performance of the application.

Comment: A good approach to improve performance is to use shader programming, in android it will give support to openGl, it will be a c++ code that will run in the gpu so you can take advantage of the parallelism.